# appium : not able to retrieve TextView child element from parent ScrollView

Tags: android, selenium, xpath, appium

I am trying to find all `TextView`  elements of `ScrollView`. I tried following but it is not helping:

```
List<AndroidElement> el1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.ScrollView/*"));
```

and

```
List<AndroidElement> el1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.ScrollView/android.widget.TextView"));
```

I also tried to find element by xpath inside an element but it gives exception as it is not supported by appium.

Is there any other way to get the `child elements` ?

Comment: What do you not helping?? Is there any exception??

Comment: Element is not available. `NoElementException` is there

Comment: Make sure provided xPath is correct

Comment: Xpath is correct.

Comment: Then you need to use implicit wait or explicit wait for element present...

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one if u want

```
WebElement parentElement=driver.findElement(by.className("android.widget.ScrollView"));

List<WebElement> childElements = parentElement.findElements(By.className("android.view.View"));
```